# How can I wrap text/comments in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: ide

What is the keyboard shortcut/menu path to wrap text, comments, etc. in Microsoft's Visual Studio Code?

I couldn't locate it in *User Preferences*. Here's the screenshot which has a lot of comments that I'd like to wrap:

[image]

I know [Sublime Text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) 2 has that option under menu *Edit* → *Wrap*, but I couldn't find anything similar in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: FWIW, I've [asked something similar on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31025502/419956) but there I'm explicitly asking for a *quick* way to do this on a per instance basis (excluding the answer given to the question here).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> File > Preferences > Settings

## New Setting UI (Searchable )

[image: Settings UI now Search Powered]

Just Search Wrap / Word Wrap

- **editor.wordWrap: "off"** - Lines will never wrap. editor.wordWrap: "on" - Lines will wrap at viewport width
- **editor.wordWrap**: "on" - Lines will wrap at viewport width.
- **editor.wordWrap**: "wordWrapColumn" - Lines will wrap at the value of editor.wordWrapColumn.
- **editor.wordWrap**: "bounded" - Lines will wrap at the minimum of viewport width and the value of editor.wordWrapColumn.

References: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_10#_word-wrap-settings-redesign and info from @jermila-dhas

## Deprecated (For History Purpose/How JSON setting should look like)

[image: File > Preferences > User Settings]

### For Beginner

Paste the following in `settings.json`

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite the default settings
{       "editor.wrappingColumn": 0 }
```

That it, it is that simpler, but probably we will having someone open source user interface for json settings.

### **For Intermediate User**

If you already have `settings.json`, just add

```
"editor.wrappingColumn": 0
```

As the settings is in JSON, last settings are without the comma `,` and setting is ending with `}` as you see in Default settings and the `settings.json` overide all the Default settings

Comment: Woww.... very nicely hidden. Well done Microsoft.

Comment: Totally agree. But the performance and features make Visual Studio code ease to use for certain languages that supported.

Comment: Take a look at all settings at https://gist.github.com/matijagrcic/8e86d8be1d600514826c#file-visual_studio_code_default_settings-js or press Press Ctrl+Shift+O in the list of default settings to see an outline of all available settings.

Comment: It was driving me nuts to have to scroll. Will need to checkout other settings. Thanks.

Comment: If you'd like to indent wrapped lines more than the initial line, use `"editor.wrappingIndent": "indent"` (or `deepIndent`).

Answer (score 5):

If you are using visual studio code v1.10, the setting `"editor.wrappingCloumn"` has been deprecated.

Use `"editor.wordWrap": "on"` instead.

More information can be found [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_10#_word-wrap-settings-redesign)

(Hoping this might help somebody)

Answer (score 3):

you can do it by this shortcut : alt + Z

Comment: This is obviously the answer to the question of "What Short Key"